# Excluding lines from a .csv based on pattern in another .csv

Tags: linux, csv

I want to compare values from 2 .csv files at Linux, excluding lines from the first file when its first column (which is always an IP) matches any of the IPs from the second file.

Any way of doing that via command line is good for me (via grep, for example) would be OK by me.

*File1.csv is:*

```
10.177.33.157,IP,Element1
10.177.33.158,IP,Element2
10.175.34.129,IP,Element3
10.175.34.130,IP,Element4
10.175.34.131,IP,Element5
```

*File2.csv:*

```
10.177.33.157    < Exists on the first file
10.177.33.158    < Exists on the first file
10.175.34.129    < Exists on the first file    
80.10.2.42       < Does not exist on the first file
80.10.3.194      < Does not exist on the first file
```

*Output file desired:*

```
10.175.34.130,IP,Element4
10.175.34.131,IP,Element5
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply with **`awk`**:

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]; next }!($1 in a)' file2.csv file1.csv
```

The output:

```
10.175.34.130,IP,Element4
10.175.34.131,IP,Element5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `-f` option from `grep` to compare files. `-v` to invert match. `-F` for fixed-strings. `man grep` goes a long way.

```
 -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains 
  zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)

-v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)

-F, --fixed-strings, --fixed-regexp
          Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by  newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX,
          --fixed-regexp is an obsoleted alias, please do not use it new scripts.)
```

Result:

```
$ grep -vFf f2.csv f1.csv
10.175.34.130,IP,Element4
10.175.34.131,IP,Element5
```